# Delete checked items when button pressed

Tags: reactjs

What's the React way of accomplishing this?

Should I set up the checkboxes as child components? -> *how do I pass the delete event to the sub-components?*

If I don't set up the checkboxes as child components will I need a for loop to loop through each item and check if it's checked, if true then delete

I'm sure there's an elegant solution but I'm new to React and I've not got my head around the concepts yet - so if there's any additional reading that can help improve my understanding then please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of right now is to have a component that contains an array of checkboxes (or at least checkbox-states). The component will display the checkboxes, along with a button which, when clicked, will iterate the array and remove all checked boxes.

If you don't want to keep everything in one component, there are multiple ways to accomplish this. You could for example just as easily keep the button and checkbox array in a parent component, and pass the array as a prop to a child component.

You might want to have a look at [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), which is a way to handle your application state (the array of checkboxes). A popular implementation of flux is [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

You can also use React without flux (as demonstrated above), and here's an article about [8 no-flux stragergies for react component communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the parent component keeps track of a list of children, as well as a list of children to delete. Every time a checkbox is checked, it's added to the delete-list, and taken off the delete-list if unchecked. When the delete button is hit, every item on the delete-list is taken off the child-list, the delete-list is cleared, and setState is called to re-render the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  // A delete-list and a list of children.
  state = {
    toDel: [],
    checks: []
  }
  // Method called when checkbox is clicked.
  recId = (idToDel) => {
    // Grab the checkbox that was clicked.
    let checker = document.getElementById(idToDel);
    if (checker.checked) {
      // Add the id to delete-list.
      this.state.toDel.push(idToDel);
    }
    else {
      // Remove the id from delete-list.
      let index = this.state.toDel.indexOf(idToDel);
      this.state.toDel.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  // Method called when delete button is clicked.
  del = () => {
    // Loop through items to delete.
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.toDel.length; i++) {
      // Convert id from string back to integer.
      let index = parseInt(this.state.toDel[i])
      // Replace the item to delete with empty string, so that every
      // other element remains in place.
      this.state.checks[index] = '';
    }
    // Re-render the component by calling setState.
    this.setState({
      toDel: [],
      checks: this.state.checks
    });
  }
  // Loading the component with child checkboxes. Children are handed
  // parent methods as event handlers.
  componentWillMount = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.state.checks.push(
        <p key={i}>
          <Check id={i.toString()} record={this.recId} />{i.toString()}
        </p>
      )
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.checks}
        <button onClick={this.del}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Check extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  state = {}
  render = () => {
    // Call the parent method on click with proper context and pass
    // id of this specific child back up to parent.
    return (
      <input type='checkbox' onClick={this.props.record.bind(null, this.props.id)} id={this.props.id} />
    );
  }
}

// Render component.
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('test-container')
);
```